Eventbridge Pipe that adds a dynamic MessageGroupID without altering the message body
I have a SQS queue which feeds a FIFO queue using an eventbridge pipe. The pipe grabs a value from the payload and then adds that to the MessageGroupID using a JSONpath expression.
import { SqsTarget } from '@aws-cdk/aws-pipes-targets-alpha';
import { SqsSource } from '@aws-cdk/aws-pipes-sources-alpha';
import * as pipes from '@aws-cdk/aws-pipes-alpha';

const pipe = new pipes.Pipe(
      this,
      'pipe-name'),
      {
        source: new SqsSource(sourceQueueSQS),
        target: new SqsTarget(targetFifoQueue, {
          messageGroupId:  '$.body.detail.some.value.used.as.id',          
        }),
        role: pipeRole,
        pipeName: 'pipe-name',
      },
    );

This is great and does add the messageGroupID as expected but for some reason it wraps the body of the message (SQSEvent) with another body. This makes deserializing in my lambda downstream more messy.
I'm not sure why it's altering the body can anyone help?

It's altering it because the target queue gets the message from EventBridge, not SQS.
By default, EventBridge passes its entire event to the target. If you want to select a specific field instead of the entire event, you can do that via the inputTransformation prop of the target and the InputTransformation.fromEventPath method:
target: new SqsTarget(targetFifoQueue, {
  messageGroupId:  '$.body.detail.some.value.used.as.id',
  inputTransformation: InputTransformation.fromEventPath('body'),
})


I'm not sure this is possible? The SqsTargetParameters prop only contains fields for MessageGroupId, MessageDeduplicationId and InputTransformation.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-pipes-targets-alpha.SqsTargetParameters.html
Unless you mean create a transformation and pass that in? I did try that and found it again wrapped it in an eventbridge event.

Ah, my mistake - didn't notice that you're using eventbridge pipes and not the regular events module.

But yes, the event is coming from EventBridge, not SQS, so it will be an EventBridge event.

this actually raises a different problem in that JSONpath removes all the escape characters to create a valid string. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-transform-target-input.html#:~:text=If%20a%20JSON,detail%22%3A%20%3Cdetail%3E%7D.) Which again makes parsing trickier.

"If a JSON path references a JSON object or array, but the variable is referenced in a string, EventBridge removes any internal quotes to ensure a valid string. For example, for a variable  pointed at $.detail, "Detail is " would result in EventBridge removing quotes from the object.
Therefore, if you want to output a JSON object based on a single JSON path variable, you must place it as a key. In this example, {"detail": }."

you can use InputTransformation.fromObject({ "body: $.body" } ) to achieve this but you end up with an extra body tag
